# Aligning images right without floating

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'm using the WordPress NextGEN Gallery to position fixed-width images inside a fluid-width `<aside>`. I'd like the images to align to the right of the `<aside>` container, but if I try to float them right, the order becomes reversed. I can't simply reverse the order of the images in WordPress either, as the number of columns of images varies with the browser window.

Is there a way to align these images to the right without floating them? I've tried setting `text-align:right` on every image and its container, but nothing's worked.

PHP/HTML:

```
<!-- Thumbnails -->
    <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>

    <div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box" <?php echo $image->style ?> >
        <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
            <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
                <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
                <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS: 
(Mostly inherited from NextGen Gallery)

```
.ngg-galleryoverview {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear:both; 
    display:block !important;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:18px;
    width:100%;
}

.ngg-galleryoverview .desc {
/* required for description */
   margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
   padding:5px;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
    display:inline;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail {
    display:inline;
    text-align: center;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail img {
    display:inline;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail img {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
    display:block;  
    margin:4px 0px 4px 5px;
    padding:4px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this in your code, but if you wrap the `img` in a `p` and set `text-align` on the `p`, it all works out.

```
<p><img src="" /></p>

p{text-align:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/x3Lx4/

Comment: Alternatively set `display: block;` and `text-align: right;` for the <a> tag wrapping your image.

Comment: This worked by setting `text-align:right` to `.ngg-galleryoverview`, but now any items that are alone in their row (ie the last images and their containers) are also aligned right. Is there a way to align the images left but the containers right?

Answer (score 0):

I had a

Text

tag in my HTML, but I didn't have any

, so I used

as a substitute for

.
PS.WhyisEverythingSoSpacedOut?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35760284)